# Can I get the jQuery-ui datepicker widget to display extra information in each cell?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to add information to each date cell in the datepicker widget (mainly, number of scheduled tasks on that day. Just wondering if it's at all possible and where would I even begin doing it?

I know I could just walk the table and change each cell individually but I was wondering if I could do add them when the widget loads.

Also, if i have to change the cells after it's loaded, how can I do it again when a month is changed?

i've implemented a function for the onChangeMonthYear event called modify_datepicker()

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { modify_datepicker() }...


function modify_datepicker() {
    var div_datepicker = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-datepicker-calendar")[0];
    alert(div_datepicker.childNodes[1].tagName);
    var tbody = div_datepicker.childNodes[1];
    var truri = tbody.childNodes;
    for(var i = 0; i < truri.length; i++) {
        tduri = truri[i].childNodes;
        for(var j = 0; j < tduri.length; j++) {
            tduri[j].innerHTML = tduri[j].innerHTML + 'a';
        }
    }   
}
```

i've also called the function after loading the datepicker. This successfully adds 'a' after each date cell but when it's called as part of the event, it's called before the table reloads with the new year and month so it has no effect. I don't know if it's supposed to happen like that or if i'm doing something wrong. If it's supposed to happen like that then I guess the only thing left is to add a delay to the function so that the table is loaded before it launches.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the source code for the jQuery UI datepicker it looks like the rendering the of the calendar is pretty hard coded. If you're interested you can see it on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#1475). You can however set the title on td for each date using the beforeShowDay event e.g.

```
var taskCounts = { date1: 2, date2: 5, date3: 0, etc, etc }

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { [true, '', taskCounts[date] ] }
});
```

Hovering over the date would then show you the number of tasks on a given day. Beyond that I think you'll have to iterate over the table to move the contents of the title attribute into the contents of the cell.

Comment: I'm working on iterating of the table contents right now and it's easier than looking into the datepicker code. However I don't know how to handle chaning months/years. If I set a onChangeMonthYear event it fires before the table gets changed. Also, any change I make is reverted when I click anywhere on the table.

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be to create your own implementation of DatePicker by subclassing the original jQuery version and then hooking an event into the end of the _updateDatepicker function which renders the updated table.